# Putting Picklist value inside SOQL query in Apex

Tags: apex, soql, picklist

I have an issue with SOQL in apex. I try to get cases with Status equal to New. Problem is about telling apex in SOQL to choose New cases. I tried it this

```
public class NewCaseListController {

public List<Case> getNewCases(){
    List<Case> result=Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, CaseNumber '+
    'FROM Case WHERE Status="New"');
        return result;

}
```

}

and this way

```
public class NewCaseListController {

public List<Case> getNewCases(){
    List<Case> result=Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, CaseNumber '+
    'FROM Case WHERE Status=New');
        return result;

}
```

}

, but both finished unsuccessfully. Could you help me to put this value inside correctly?

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your queries is that you've used `"` in one and nothing in another. You need to use apostrophes or `'`. The easiest way to do this is to escape the apostrophies wrapping "new". You can do this by preceeding those apostrophies with a slash. So, your query will look like this:

```
'SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Status=\'New\''
```

Salesforce will ignore anything directly proceeding the `\`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
List<Case> result = new List<Case>([SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Status = 'New']);
```